# Can I do a dry run with homebrew to see the details of what will be installed and how?

Tags: homebrew

Is it possible to run in a verbose mode where it doesn't actually install the package, but just details from where and how it will be install the package?

Answer (score 52):

You can run `brew outdated` to see a list of outdated packages that will be upgraded when running `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 13):

The closest you'll find is to show the dependencies of the package you're trying to install:

`$ brew deps ruby`

Will list the packages of ruby. You can then use:

`$ brew list`

to see which packages you have installed. From these two commands, you will be able to tell which packages will be installed by `brew install ruby`

Answer (score 6):

The `brew install --dry-run` feature was [recently added](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/13706).

```
brew install --dry-run vim
==> Would install 1 formula:
vim
==> Would install 5 dependencies for vim:
lua berkeley-db perl libyaml ruby
```

Comment: The `--dry-run` is also available on other commands like `brew upgrade`, you can check the docs: `brew help <command> | less`

Answer (score 0):

I've used gentoo linux quite a bit in the past, and their portage system has a nice 'pretend' option for installing packages, the closest I've found for brew is:

brew list (package name)

brew list ruby gives me:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/tilt
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/testrb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/ri
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/rdoc
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/rake
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/rackup
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/irb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/gem
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/bin/erb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/include/ruby-1.9.1/ (21 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/ (998 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ (3 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/share/man/ (5 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/share/ri/ (9522 files)
```

But I'm guessing you're looking for more info than this?

Comment: That'll only allow you to list the contents of packages that are already installed, not ones that haven't been installed yet.